# Stackexchange.Redis ListRightPush "Invalid number of arguments"

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to do a batch save into a redis list. It works fine for a batch of one, but for two, I get an exception saying I have an invalid number of arguments. here is my code:

```
List<RedisValue> toWrite = new List<RedisValue>(batchSize);
UserRequest r;
while (toWrite.Count < batchSize && _saveQueque.TryDequeue(out r))
{
     toWrite.Add(Serialize(r));
}

if (toWrite.Count > 0)
{
     GetDB().ListRightPush(key, toWrite.ToArray()); //Throws exception
     GetDB().KeyExpire(key, DateTime.Now.AddHours(4), CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Could it be the null terminators in my serialization scheme?

Comment: What server version are you using? the varadic `rpush` is only available from 2.4 onwards

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, that was the problem, I was running an old version locally, the problem does not occur in production where we are using a newer redis version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an old version of redis; the multi-value (varadic) version of `rpush` was added in v2.4 of redis - you'll need *at least that version* to use this API.